# How secure is ssh port tunneling?

Tags: ssh, port, openssh, forward

I am trying to figure out what happens when I do a port forward using OpenSSH (`ssh -L <local_port>:<remote_host_2> -fN <remote_host_1>`), and how it compares to simply ssh'ing to a remote host.

More specifically, I wonder if `remote_host_1` is compromised, can it sniff the traffic
that I am sending to `remote_host_2`? From the manfile of ssh, it seems that the answer to this question is positive and thus the chain (if, e.g., I am trying to `telnet` to `remote_host_2` via `remote_host_1`) looks like this:
**local_host --[secure]--> remote_host_1 --[open]--> remote_host_2** .

However, what happens if I ssh to the `remote_host_2` via the aforementioned port forward (`ssh <local_host> -p <local_port>`)? Is it correct, that even if the `remote_host_1` is compromised, there is no danger? In other words, is the following true in that case:
**local_host --[double encryption]--> remote_host_1 --> [single encryption] --> remote_host_2** .

Finally, is it correct that the second situation is still different from ssh'ing to `remote_host_1` and ssh'ing to `remote_host_2` from it, in the sense that if `remote_host_1` is compromised, it can log everything?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why would you use a tunnel instead of `ProxyCommand`?

Comment: Because I do not see why one should do that. Are there any advantages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, all the questions should be answered 'yes'.

A reference that answers all my questions is the chapter 11 of "SSH, The Secure Shell" by Daniel J. Barrett & Richard Silverman. An excerpt with all the relevant info can be found [here](http://oreilly.com/catalog/sshtdg/chapter/ch11.html).

I again thank Simon and EJP for their answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is encrypted between the client and SSH. From SSH to the target port it is plaintext of course, or rather it is exactly what you are sending over the tunnel to the target application. Only the tunnel part is encrypted.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! However, this does not answer any of my questions about logging/sniffing.

Comment: @user1577683 In what way does 'plaintext' and 'only the tunnel part is encrypted' not answer your questions? Plaintext can be sniffed, ciphertext can't.